# How to track , on url change in React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

this is App.js -
this is good

```
<Route path='/page1'>
     <Page1 />
 </Route>
```

this is "/page1"

```
var location = window.location.href
<Link to="/page1/2">
    <p>Click to change</p>
</Link>
```

if i click on that paragraf it change url into /page1/2  but var location isnt changed its still /page1  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                       I want when url chaged  to set var location to new location (window.location.href)(/page1/2)

//  or i need just show me how to  "on url changed" do something what-ever maybe alert('url changed') or console.log('url changed')

Comment: Please share a more complete code example. It's unclear what you are asking or want the code to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using react-router, use `useLocation` hook to get the path.

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export const App = () => {
  let location = useLocation();
  return <div>...</div>;
}
```